# Blue Prism attach Mainframe application

Tags: automation, mainframe

Im applying Mainframe automation in Blue Prism for a process using Micro focus Reflection for Destkop 16 (.NET API). I don't however find the attach action when i use the Navigate stage and place the root of the application in the element column. In the application modeller i use the following path to session file: S:\Documents\Attachmate\Reflection\Refl2014\hiddenName.rd3x

Does anyone have an idea on how to attach to the mainframe window?

Thx for the help!